# How to populate data in combo box from sql server

Tags: vb6

I have a combo box name cbSection

how can i populate the data from sql server in combo box ?

Any idea will help

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is direct from [VbForums](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?380145-Database-How-can-I-fill-a-combobox-with-values-in-a-database) (I take no credit for the code!), first result for a quick Google search.

```
Dim strSQL as String    'Declare the variables we need 
Dim oRS as ADODB.Recordset
  Set oRS = New ADODB.Recordset

                           'Load the data
'** change this SQL to load the data you want.
  strSQL = "SELECT Colour FROM Colours"

'** change oConn to the name of your Connection object
  oRS.Open strSQL, oConn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
                           'Fill the combo box (or ListBox)
'** change the name of the combo to the one you want to fill
  With cboColour
    .Clear
    Do While Not oRS.EOF
'** change the name of the field here to the one you want to show
      .AddItem oRS.fields("Colour").value
      oRS.MoveNext
    Loop
  End With

                           'Tidy up
  oRS.Close
  Set oRS = Nothing
```